# Как мне получить айпи, кто подключен к моему wifi

Tags: c++, wifi, arp

У меня есть функция, которая получает arp таблицу, в ней разные ип и выделяется 2ое

```
Address: 192.168.1.1
Phys Addr Len: 6
Phys Address: 18:62:2c:f7:cd:8d
Index:  24
Type:   3

192.168.1.255
******************************************************************************
Address: 192.168.1.255
Phys Addr Len: 6
Phys Address: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Index:  24
Type:   4
```

Как я прочитал, это ип роутера, но как мне получить ip подключенных устройств

```
Остальные ип которые в arp таблице: выглядят по типу 255....
```

Comment: В web-панели роутера скорее всего есть страничка со списком устройств. Можно подключиться к нему и считывать этот список. Но это будет способ, завязанный на конкретную модель роутера.

Comment: @ Мне бы как-то это через arp хотелось бы делать, т.к к веб панеи скорее всего доступа не будет?

Comment: нет доступа к роутеру - нет дополнительной информации. В любом случае некоторые устройства будут "невидимы". Но просто слушайте сеть и найдете много полезной информации.

Comment: @KoVadim досступ к роутеру есть, но не всегда будет доступ к странице роутера. Поэтому нужен способ так получать(через пк) все ip

Comment: какой же это доступ, если нет доступа к админке? физический? в смысле вижу его и потрогать могу?

Comment: @KoVadim я имел ввиду доступ подключения, ладно я вас понял, спс

Comment: иметь пароль к вайфай - это не иметь доступ к роутеру:)

Answer (score 3):

Для того чтоб заполнить таблицу арп - нужно выполнить запросы по ип.

Делаешь пинг для всех ип в локальной сети, если есть соседи - они там появятся.

Сейчас ваш компьютер общается только с роутером, поэтому в арп нет записей от других устройств.

Comment: это работает только в локальных домашних сетях. У любого маломальского роутера есть возможность изолировать каждого клиента и этот способ не будет работать

Comment: По идее arp таблица из моего роутера, она по идее должна быть заполнена. Я получаю её через метод `GetIpNetTable`

Comment: @vazgen5678 GetIpNetTable получает таблицу этой машины, а не роутера

Comment: @user7860670 а какой тогде метод будет давать мне таблицу роутера, не подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: @vazgen5678 зависит от модели роутера ;)

Comment: @eri я думал есть единая функция, которая может взять с любого роутера

Comment: @eri можете мне наводку дать, или пример на любой модели роутера, чтобы я понял куда мне копать

Comment: @vazgen5678 просканируй сеть и возьми с хоста

Comment: @eri можешь по подробнее объяснить, я +- новичок в этой теме)